# Inner and outer measure (Lebesgue Measure in the real line)

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

If $E$ is an measureble set in the real line , with $m(E)=\infty$, then $\forall A \subset E$ is true that:
$$ m_*(A)+m^*(E-A) = \infty \quad? $$
I think this statement is false!!!

Mi attempt:

Let $E_n=[n,n+1),\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$,observe that how $E_n\cap E_m=\emptyset , d(E_n,E_m)>0$, since $$E=\bigcup E_n$$ then $$m(E)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} m(E_n)=\infty$$(Ok $m(E)=\infty$).

we know that $\exists A\subset E_0\subset [0,1],$such that, $m_*(A)=0$ and $m^*(A)=1$.

Repeat this construction in every $E_n$ , so
$A_n\subset E_n:m_*(A_n)=0$ and $m^*(A_n)=1$.

How the sets $A_n$ they are dijoints and with positive distance ( by construction), since $$ A=\bigcup_{n=0}^{\infty} A_n$$ then follow that $$m_*(A)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}m_*(A_n)=0$$

Finally , how $A_n\subset E_n$ and $m(E_n)<\infty$, then $m*(E_n-A_n)=m^*(E_n)+m^*(A_n)=1-1=0$.

But $$m^*(E-A)\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}m^*(E_n-A_n)=0$$

Can you help me to verify if this mi prove is correct.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1):

Since $m_*(A)=0$, we have $m^*(E-A)=1$. The same holds for each $E_n$ and $A_n$. So the last equation in your proof is not correct. The $0$ at the end should be $\infty$, and that destroys the proof.

A minor point: The distance between $E_n$ and $E_{n+1}$ is $0$. The reason this correction is minor is that your argument didn't use any information about distance.